# entity framework with linq query and stored expression error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to search for file name inside a database table

If the user entered too many words in the input field I want to find all the file names that contain all the words entered.

```
    private bool SmartSearch(string textTosSearchIn, string textTosSearch)
    {
        textTosSearch = textTosSearch.ToLower();
        textTosSearch = textTosSearchIn.ToLower();
        var allStrings = textTosSearch.Split(' ');

        foreach (var item in allStrings)
        {

            if (!textTosSearchIn.Contains(item.Trim()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

r = con.MyFiles.Where(x => SmartSearch(fname.Text, x.FileName)).ToList();
```

this error fired

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SmartSearch(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I make a stored expression to do this search in linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework does not execute C# code on server side. It translates C# code which you have on client side to SQL text command, and then executes SQL on server. So, in your case EF cannot translate custom C# method `SmartSearch` into SQL.

From your code it looks like you have `FileName` field in database, which you split by white space (pretty strange to me). Then you check if any of these parts contained in text you have on client. Unfortunately `String.Split` cannot be translated into SQL, so either move filtering to client

```
 con.MyFiles.AsEnumerable() // transfers all data from db to client
            .Where(f => SmartSearch(fname.Text, f.FileName))
            .ToList();
```

or consider to re-work your filtering algorithm. E.g. getting all file names which have any of entered words looks to me like this:

```
 var words = fname.Text.Split();
 var files = con.MyFiles.Where(f => words.Any(w => f.FileName.Contains(w)));
```

Answer (score 0):

SmartSearch can't be translated in SQL. If you want use this function in LINQ, you may, previously, get List of yout object, and then filter:

```
con.MyFiles.ToList().Where(x => SmartSearch(fname.Text, x.FileName)).ToList();
```

But this will be work slowly (because you get all `MyFiles` in program)

Also you may write stored function in SQL (for your smartSearch), get it in EntityFramework and then call this function in LINQ ([link to example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)).